# JAVA: How to split array into multiple array from values where "ViewAll" is title of the arrays

Tags: java

```
String[] str={"Data1 ViewAll","ay","ax","Data2 ViewAll","bx","by","bz","Data3 ViewAll","cx","cz"}
```

I want to seprate values from the above array.

i.e.

```
String Data2ViewAll = {"bx","by","bz"};
String Data3ViewAll = {"cx","cz"};
```

note: we can ignore the name of the arrays.

p.s.

```
I have differentiated the titles from the main String array.

ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int j=0; j<str.length; j++) {
        if(str[j].contains("View All")) {
            System.out.println("Title : "+str[j]);
            titleList.add(str[j]);
        }
}
```

Comment: What have your tried? Please supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Ambro-r I have tried above code in p.s.

Comment: Perhaps should you use a `Map`?

Comment: Is this a [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/287138) question?

Comment: Yes...! This worked with List and ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a map. Like this:

```
    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> list = null;
    for (String elm: str) {
        if (elm.contains("ViewAll")) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(elm, list);
        } else if (list != null) {
            list.add(elm);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

This will give you:

```
{Data3 ViewAll=[cx, cz], Data2 ViewAll=[bx, by, bz], Data1 ViewAll=[ay, ax]}
```

Comment: Nice, just does not work if you start repeating your keys. i.e. `String[] str={"Data1 ViewAll","ay","ax","Data1 ViewAll","bx","by","bz","Data1 ViewAll","cx","cz"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> cList = null;
for (String elm: str) {
    if (elm.endsWith("ViewAll")) {
        cList = new ArrayList<>();
        lists.add(cList);
    } else if (cList != null) {
        cList.add(elm);
    }
}

for (List<String> list: lists) {
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using **startsWith** method in String we can split the one string array into multiple array. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String[] str={"Data1 ViewAll","ay","ax","Data2 ViewAll","bx","by","bz","Data3 ViewAll","cx","cz"};
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList b = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i =0; i<str.length;i++){
            if(str[i].startsWith("b")){
                a.add(str[i]);
            }
            if(str[i].startsWith("c")){
                b.add(str[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a `Map` as per @Maurice's suggestion. Basically each time you encounter an entry with *ViewAll* you put a new entry into your `Map` and if your `Map` already contains that entry, then you just append to it.

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
  String[] str = {"Data1 ViewAll","ay","ax","Data2 ViewAll","bx","by","bz","Data3 ViewAll","cx","cz"};
  Map<String, List<String>> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
  String currentKey = "";
  for(String element : str) {
    if(element.contains("ViewAll")) {
      currentKey = element;
    } else if(!currentKey.isEmpty()) {
      if(!stringMap.containsKey(currentKey)) {
        stringMap.put(currentKey, new ArrayList<>());
      }
      stringMap.get(currentKey).add(element);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(stringMap.toString());
}
```